# Why its got the name piecewise continuous function?

Tags: functions

[image: piecewise continuous function]

Above image is of a piecewise continuous function
between [x0,x4],
but, I have a doubt.
the function not defined at x1. i.e f(x1) not defined
and function breaks at x1. But, why we still call this
piecewise continuous function? Some one could you please explain why we call this piecewise continuous?

Comment: The domain is made up of pieces on which it is continuous. To be more precise, the domain is a union of intervals on whose interior the function is continuous.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thank you, But what about function not defined at x1

Comment: Let $f:D\to\mathbb R$ be a function with the domain $D\subseteq \mathbb R$. It is said to be "continuous at $x$" for some $x\in D$ if <insert your definition of continuity>. It is said to be "continuous" if it is continuous at all points in its domain. So what happens at points that lie outside its domain has no bearing at all for its continuity. Since your function isn't defined at $x_1$, we just don't care about $x_1$ as far as continuity is concerned, because $x_1$ is not in the domain of the function.